# Ubuntu 16.04.1 Install does not activate network adapter

Tags: networking, wired

when I boot from CD/DVD for Ubuntu 16.04.1 it finds and uses the network adapter, after installing the OS and rebooting the network adapter is not found or listed as available. Booting again from CD/DVD the Ubuntu software finds the adapter, rebooting on the hard drive no network adapter is found.

```
Network controller [0200] Broadcom Corp BCM4311 802.11 b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
  Kernel driver in use: wl
  Kernel Modual : wl
Ethernet controller [0280] Broadcom Corp BCM4401.b0 100 base-tx [14e4:170c] (rev 02)
  Kernel Modual: b44
```

Comment: Connect an Ehernet cable and chances are the required additional driver for your WiFi is automatically downloaded, installed and set up. If not open your System Settings > Software Properties > Additional Drivers (tab), select it and apply.

Comment: It would be better to ask a separate question for each network adapter. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx for the Wi-Fi driver, it has a lot of info to parse and I have a movie to watch, just commenting for reference, probably will make an answer out of it later.

Comment: Hey can u edit question and post output of cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf @CMora42

Comment: @minigeek here is the output: blacklist b43 blacklist b43legacy blacklist ssb blacklist bcm43xx blacklist brcm80211 blacklist brcmfmac blacklist brcmsmac blacklist bcma blacklist b44  Install modprobe -r b43 b44 b43legacy ssb; modprobe --ignore - install wl; modprobe -- ignore - install b44

Comment: Edit this file using sudo gedit.....path.. and remove those lines : blacklist b44 install modprobe -r b43 ..*till*....--ignore -install b44... Delete those line save file and restart

Comment: File should contain only : blacklist b43 blacklist b43legacy blacklist ssb #blacklist bcm43xx #blacklist brcm80211 blacklist brcmsmac blacklist bcma....there isn't hashtag in your file at 2 lines put it

Comment: After putting hashtag..and deleting those lines ..let me know what happenes @CMora42

Comment: @minigeek Fantastic, thank you Minigeek, removing those lines and placing the # at the points you suggested worked like a charm. I learned something today!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wl` is a wrong driver for your wireless adapter. Remove the `wl` driver by

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and reboot. Wired network should work after that. Connect by wire and run

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

After reboot both wireless and wired adapters should work.

Comment: wireless is also now working